# How to parse string with regular expression

Tags: c#

How can I get List() from this text:

```
For the iPhone do the following:<ul><li>Go to AppStore</li><li>Search by him</li><li>Download</li></ul>
```

that should consist :Go to AppStore,
                     Search by him, 
                     Download

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap in an XML root element and use LINQ to XML:

```
var xml = "For the iPhone do the following:<ul><li>Go to AppStore</li><li>Search by him</li><li>Download</li></ul>";
xml = "<r>"+xml+"</r>"; 
var ele = XElement.Parse(xml);  
var lists = ele.Descendants("li").Select(e => e.Value).ToList();
```

Returns in `lists`:

```
Go to AppStore 
Search by him 
Download
```

Comment: +1 for using XML, though in small cases as this, is it not faster to just parse the string?

Answer (score 5):

Load the string up into the [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) then select all `li` elements inner text.

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml("following:<ul><li>Go to AppStore</li><li>Search by him</li><li>Download</li></ul>");

var uls = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("li").Select(d => d.InnerText);
foreach (var ul in uls)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ul);
}
```

Comment: +1 for HTML in the wild, you can't rely on well-formed XHTML, so Agility Pack is needed.